# How to fix SignaLink non-linearity problem?

Tags: digital-modes, testing, linearity

I decided to check the linearity of my Yaesu FT-891 signal using an RF sampler and an oscilloscope. To generate two-tone (1550 Hz, 2150 Hz) signal I used Audacity. To connect the transceiver to the PC (MacBook Pro 2018) I used SignaLink.

Surprisingly turned out that the signal is not quite linear:

[image]

No matter how I change to output volume this is the best I can get. For a comparison, here is the exact same signal when another (DIY) digital interface is used:

[image]

Thus I'm quite sure that the problem is with SignaLink. However I have little idea what exactly is causing it or even where to start from. I wonder whether this is a known problem and  maybe someone already described a mod to fix it (I didn't manage to find one). If there is no known solution a little piece of advice on how to debug the issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: If anyone is interested I've published the schematic of the DIY interface: https://eax.me/diy-digital-mode-interface/

Comment: Also if anyone is interested here is how typical IMD looks like in WSJT-X https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/12976/13598

Answer (score 2):

It might be the transformers frequency response is not flat. Try replacing them with reputable units that have a published frequency response such as [here](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/tamura/TTC-105/MT4134-ND/285701). See more signalink tweaks [here](http://www.frenning.dk/OZ1PIF_HOMEPAGE/SignaLinkUSB-mods.html).